# UINavigationController not showing on modal view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, navigationbar

I am showing up programmatically a modal view controller when the user presses a button on the main view controller. The problem I have is that the modal view is displayed without the navigation bar.

How could I make the bar appear? Please find my code and let me know what is missing or wrong:

```
-(void)appInfoButtonPressed:(id)sender {
infoViewController *iVC=[[infoViewController alloc] init];
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:iVC animated:YES completion:nil];
UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:iVC];
[self presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Also in an attempt the dismiss the modal view I have the intention to use the line below:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Should I include this line in a method of the main view controller or in a method of the modal view controller itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete [self presentViewController:iVC animated:YES completion:nil]; 
Only to present the UINavigationController.

By the way: It isn't suitable to name a UINavigationController with "navBar".

```
-(void)appInfoButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    infoViewController *iVC=[[infoViewController alloc] init];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:iVC];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Fixed! I also found the answered to the second part of my question. Just added this method to the modal view controller

-(void)dismissModal:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
 import UIKit

class ListVC: UIViewController {


    // MARK: - Init
    override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

        //Background of the first screen
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow

        //Calling the instance of the navigation controller
        let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

        //Defining the black theme on the navigation controller
        nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black

        //Defining the white characters to make contrast with the black theme on the navigation controller
        nav?.tintColor = UIColor.white

        //Defining the custom color of the title font from navigation controller
        nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange]

        //Defining the title of the navigation controller
        nav?.topItem?.title = "List"

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "AddBtn"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(hello))



//        print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)

           let realm = try! Realm()

           print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)

       }


    // MARK: - Selector

    /// A selector function that is called when the 'add' button is pressed on the navigation controller
    @objc func hello() {

        //Instance of the second screen
        let addVC = AddVC()

        //Add the navigationController to the new viewController
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: addVC)

        //Presenting the second screen modally
        navigationController?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
//Other class
import UIKit

class AddVC: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Background of the view
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        //Calling the instance of the navigation controller
        let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

        //Initialize the title for the ViewController
        nav?.topItem?.title = "Andrey"

        // Initialize the right bar button item
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = setUpSaveButton()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }

    /// Function that returns the "Save" bar button item
    private func setUpSaveButton() -> UIBarButtonItem {
        let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveAction))
        button.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemBlue],
                                      for: .normal)

        return button
    }

    @objc func saveAction() {
        print("Saving..")
    }
}
```